# Proper way to retrieve object(s) from list of objects, where object(s) meet some criteria

Tags: python, oop

I'm not quite sure how to phrase this question; sorry if it's misleading or a duplicate.

Lets say I have a class:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, num_apples):
        self.apples = num_apples

a = MyClass(1)
b = MyClass(3)
c = MyClass(2)
```

If I want to find the most apples that any of these objects have, it is simple:

```
group = [a, b, c]
most_apples = max([g.apples for g in group])  # == 3
```

But what if I want to retrieve the object that has 3 apples instead of 3? I could do something like:

```
has_most_apples = [g for g in group if g.apples == most_apples][0] # == b
```

So my question is: is there a more elegant/pythonic way to do this?

Actually now that I've written this out, it doesn't seem so bad. Question still stands though. I'm curious :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `max` function takes a `key` argument to decide how to calculate the max.  You can use `max(group, key=lambda x: x.apples)` to get the object that has the largest `apples` value.

Comment: Brilliant, I wasn't aware of the key argument. Thanks for the little explanation as well.

Answer (score 2):

Re-reading your question, if you have multiple apples, you might want to extend to a filter function --

```
>>> target_value = 3
>>> a = MyClass(1)
>>> b = MyClass(3)
>>> c = MyClass(2)
>>> d = MyClass(3)
>>> group = [a,b,c,d]
>>> new_group = filter(lambda x : x.apples==target_value,group)
>>> new_group[0] is b
True
>>> new_group[1] is d
True
```

To make it readable, you can implement your own function

```
>>> def get_apples(num_apples):
        return lambda x : x.apples==num_apples
>>> new_group = filter(get_apples(3),group)
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are good. But remember that your code

```
has_most_apples = [g for g in group if g.apples == most_apples][0]
```

will only return the first element that has the highest number of apples. There may be more than one abject that can do so.

Answer (score 0):

You could sort your list on the `apples` attribute and then take the first element.

```
from operator import attrgetter

a = MyClass(1)
b = MyClass(3)
c = MyClass(2)

group = [a, b, c]

has_most_apples = sorted(group, key=attrgetter('apples'), reverse=True)[0]
```

This, of course, has the same caveat that **tdk** mentions of only returning one element even if there are multiple with the same number of apples.